# Need help creating insertion method for a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, insertion

So Im trying to make a Linked List class in C++ and im having trouble with inserting new elements. Im trying to insert them in such a way that at any point the Linked List will always be in ascending order, I believe its called insertion sort. Anyway I have an issue with my insertion method where if I try to insert more than one element I get some sort of error with my getNext method which simply gets the pointer to the next node in the list. If I just insert data one after the other my program works fine but for some reason this is giving me problems, any ideas what it could be?

Insertion Method:

```
void insert(int data){
    ListNode *NewNode = new ListNode(data, NULL);
    ListNode *temp = Head;
    if(Head -> getNext() == NULL){
        Head -> setNext(NewNode);
        cout<<data<<" has been inserted"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        while((temp -> getNext() != NULL) || (temp -> getNext() -> getData() < data)){
            temp = temp -> getNext();

        }
        if(temp -> getData() == data){
                cout<<"Data is already in list"<<endl;
                return;
            }
        if(temp -> getNext() != NULL){
            temp ->setNext(NewNode);
            cout<<data<<" has been inserted"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        if(temp -> getNext() -> getData() > data){
            NewNode -> setNext(temp -> getNext());
            temp ->setNext(NewNode);
            cout<<data<<" has been inserted"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shall that be a sorted list? BTW: THere are a thousand and one list implementations on this site.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, fix this `if(Head -> getNext() == NULL)`. This doesn't cover the possibility of starting with an empty list, so check if `Head == NULL` and if true, your new node becomes Head.

Without looking at the rest of the code, your while loop condition is wrong. The loop will just run until the next node is NULL because the check for data will short circuit. Try using the and operator.

`while((temp -> getNext() != NULL) && (temp -> getNext() -> getData() < data))`

Then the loop while stop if the next node is NULL or the next node's data is greater than the data trying to be added. Once the loop is done, you have to insert the logic to figure out which case it was.